# Reverse proxy from nginx to squid

Tags: nginx, proxy, squid

Требуется связка: client <-> nginx <-> squid <-> site.

В nginx:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://37.59.62.38:8080/https://www.google.com;
}
```

37.59.62.38:8080 - прокси(squid).

Ответ от squid:
[image: Error. The requested URL could not be retrieved]

Проблема в том, что заголовок получается: "GET /https://www.google.com".
Требуется убрать первый "/", именно необходимо реализовать в nginx.

Похожий вопрос:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331813/reverse-proxy-from-nginx-to-squid

Comment: А для чего в этой связке вообще Squid, почему бы не проксировать сразу к гуглу? В этом "похожем вопросе" рассматривается размещение Squid как прокси для доступа к **любому** сайту через этот узел.

Comment: Необходима такая реализация.

Comment: Вы не ответили на вопрос.

Comment: Google здесь для примера.

Comment: Да он и неважен, какой бы узел там ни был -- зачем Squid, если в `proxy_pass` можно указать сразу узел-цель, минуя Squid?

Comment: Nginx стоит на сервере с одним IP, через него нужно "общаться" с другими сайтами, если вдруг IP по непонятным причинам будет заблокирован, то будут использоваться резервные прокси.
Альтернативные подходы не интересуют, требуется сделать все через nginx.

Comment: Так понятнее, спасибо. Допишите вопрос.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что nginx тут нужен для балансировки (распределения пользователей по проксям) и failover'а (переключением пользователя на новый прокси, если исходный откажет), а squid'ов у вас ожидается много?

Comment: Можно и так сказать, проблема только в подключении к squid через nginx..

Comment: Можно реализовать очень легко через тот же curl, только в этом случае потребуется подключать php-fpm, но это лишняя нагрузка, не подходит.

Comment: тут два варианта) - или это троллинг, или объясните задачу всей этой затеи

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос можно найти тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331813/reverse-proxy-from-nginx-to-squid/49202210#49202210

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, попробую как найдется время, так как уже не так срочно как несколько месяцев назад)